# What is this called? Oak Cabinet Cap?

Tags: cabinets

Can anyone help me figure out what these end caps are called?  The panel sticks out past the cabinet by about a 1/4" so these end caps are hollow and fit over the excess panel.

What are these called and where can I buy new ones?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I was on a job and somebody was asking for that, they'd call it the little stile on the kick. I've never heard it given a real name.

I doubt you can buy one off the shelf. You can find a cabinetmaker or woodworker that'll make you one, though. Look for a smaller shop and bring cookies as well as money. If you have the old one, bring it with you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to repair that one.

1. Gently pop it off from the top with a putty knife.
2. Pull the nails from the back side with a locking plier or channel-lock.
3. Clamp the block across the middle to prevent it from cracking completely apart. A C-clamp or small bar clamp will do. Protect the wood with cardboard.
4. From the wall side, about 2" up, drill a pilot hole for a 1-1/4" drywall screw, the same size or a hair smaller than the screw shaft. Mark your bit with tape to avoid running too far.
5. Countersink for the screw head. A 3/8" bit can work if you don't have a countersink bit. Make sure it's not a pilot-point bit that will grab the wood aggressively and wreck things.
6. Remove the clamp and *very gently* spread the crack and squeeze it full of wood glue. Reinstall the clamp and wipe away all excess glue with a damp cloth.
7. Run your drywall screw in gently but snugly and let the assembly dry for a couple hours.
8. Sand, stain, varnish.
9. Reinstall with project adhesive, silicone caulk, or another robust product. If you want to nail it, pre-drill the size of the nail shaft.